# Getting a json array from dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have 4 dictionaries with different names given as below...

```
let dict = [
    "ResolutionID": [1: "101", 2: "102", 3: "103", 0: "100"],
    
    "Planned":   [3: "Y", 1: "Y", 2: "Y"],
    
    "Done":  [2: "Y"],
    
    "Who": [2: "qw", 0: "bcc"]
]
```

The names of these dictionaries correspond to the names of keys of my json object and the keys in the above dictionaries (0,1,2 etc.) correspond to the total number of json objects in my array. So in the above case since the max key among the dictionaries is 3, I'll have 4 objects in my json array(0-3)

So I wanted to create a json array that finally looks like so...

```
[
  {
    "ResolutionID":100,
    "Who":"bcc",
    "Planned":"",
    "Done":""
  },
  {
    "ResolutionID":101,
    "Who":"",
    "Planned":"Y",
    "Done":""
  },
  {
    "ResolutionID":102,
    "Who":"qw",
    "Planned":"Y",
    "Done":"Y"
  },
  {
    "ResolutionID":103,
    "Who":"",
    "Planned":"Y",
    "Done":""
  }
]
```

I tried using `merge` and `merging`. But it didn't work...

Now I'm not sure how to achieve this result...

EDIT: This is what I've tried..

I tried using a for-loop to compare same keys and then adding them to an array. But it's assigning wrong values. This is what I tried...

```
for (indexSel,plantCode) in selectionOptionDic {
    resolutionDict["ResolutionID"] = plantCode
    for (indexPL,planned) in selectionPlannedDic {
        if indexPL == indexSel {
            resolutionDict["Planned"] = planned
        }
        for (indexDone,done) in selectionDoneDic {
            if indexDone == indexPL {
                resolutionDict["Done"] = done
            }
            for (indexWho,text) in selectionWhoDic {
                if indexWho == indexDone {
                    resolutionDict["Who"] = text
                }
                
            }
        }
        arrayOfResolutions.append(resolutionDict)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code to show what you have tried.

Comment: have edited the question with what I've tried @JoakimDanielson

Comment: @user987654 - I updated your question to make it clearer, but next time, please make sure that you format it correctly before posting, and show as much of the code as you can to remove ambiguity

Comment: sure @NewDev...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your end goal is a json array I think it is better to work with a struct that implements `Codable`

```
struct Resolution: Codable {
    let resolutionId: String
    let planned: String
    let done: String
    let who: String

    init(id: String, planned: String?, done: String?, who: String?) {
        self.resolutionId = id
        self.planned = planned ?? ""
        self.done = done ?? ""
        self.who = who ?? ""
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case resolutionId = "ResolutionID"
        case planned = "Planned"
        case done = "Done"
        case who = "Who"
    }
}
```

and then do the conversion as follows

```
let arrayOfResolutions = selectionOptionDic.map { 
    Resolution(id: $0.value,
               planned: selectionPlannedDic[$0.key],
               done: selectionDoneDic[$0.key],
               who: selectionWhoDic[$0.key])
}
```

Comment: This is what I got @JJoakim Danielson `[
MyApp.Resolution(resolutionId: "100", planned: "", done: "", who: "gcnhh"), 
MyApp.Resolution(resolutionId: "101", planned: "Y", done: "Y", who: ""), 
MyApp.Resolution(resolutionId: "102", planned: "Y", done: "", who: "cd"), 
MyApp.Resolution(resolutionId: "103", planned: "Y", done: "", who: "")
]`. The array is correctly formed..:)..But how can I have it in the json format like i mentioned in the question..?

Comment: @user987654 like I wrote, the struct conforms to Codable so use JSONEncoder to encode it to json

Comment: Sorry for coming back to this again @Joakim Danielson...Your answer was very helpful. Would you maybe mind explaining in a couple of lines as to how the `map` function you used here works. I'm not able to get it completely. Please excuse me once again..